# Prime number as factor of square of other number

Tags: prime-numbers, factoring, square-numbers

Lets $p$ be a prime number, and $x$ any natural number. 
If $p$ is factor of $x^2$, then $p$ is factor of $x$?
I need this in one exercise, and i also want to somehow prove if it's true.

I tried to list all of numbers i get from prime factorization of $x$ and then try to show that this postulat is true, but i'm not sure if its ok to do this this way.

Comment: Hint:  in general, if a prime $p$ divides a product $ab$ then it must divide at least one of $a,b$.

Comment: In this case, you let $a=x$ and $b=x$.

Comment: wow, thanks, that feels pretty obvious right now. can i get some link with a detailed prove?

Comment: This result appears in Euclid and is widely regarded as the precursor to the proof of Unique Factorization in the natural numbers.  The wiki article on [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) is a good introduction.

Comment: @yossi it will be better if you try with the *hints* given above. Then you can post your answer so that others can verify whether your understanding is correct or not.

Comment: @lulu In fact said Prime Divisor Property is equivalent to *uniqueness* of  prime factorizations (the proof is short and easy).

Comment: If the linked answers do not suffice then either post comments on them or make your question more specific and we can reopen it.